# Trying to print colored source code from TextMate - "Could not locate your theme file!"

Tags: printing, colors, textmate

I'm trying to print some Java source code with syntax coloring from TextMate, and the recommended way to do that seems to be to generate HTML from the source first. However, when I choose Bundles --> TextMate --> Create HTML from document, the message "Could not locate your theme file!" appears. Not even knowing what a "theme file" is, I'm pretty lost as to how I can fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I (think I) figured it out. Going into Preferences --> Fonts & Colors and selecting the "Mac Classic" color theme (which was already selected, BTW) seemingly recreated whatever it was that was missing. HTML generation now works fine.

Comment: Thanks for adding this response, it worked for me also after getting the "Cloud not locate..." error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes textmate does not work very well with colored printing(using HTML). You can use xcode to print the file. Just remember to choose the theme when printing.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm going to give the simplest possible answer because it worked for me (OSX Monterey 12.6, Textmate version 2.0.23)

Just print it. It will print it in color.

I don't think it used to just work like that, but for me, now it does with no modifications whatsoever